# Photoshop automatically scaling down image on PNG export, how to export at full ratio?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png

**How to export an image from Photoshop CC with dimensions (15300 x 10500) to one PNG without scaling down?**

I have multiple images at 15300 x 10500 pixel and created them at this size. However, I can not export it at this ratio to PNG. No matter which way I try "export as ...", "For Web" or "Fast export", I can not put the scaling to 100%. At "Export as ..." maximum is 78%, at "For Web" it is 53,54%. Different images (at the same original pixel dimensions) give the same maximum.

There is a white background and many areas with the same color, so file size is not an issue. The actual file size on the smaller ratios is <2MB.

If i "export layers" the background layer is at its full size, but if I create a merged layer and try to export that single layer it is scaled down, too.

At Illustrator I don't have trouble exporting to full size.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***"save as ..."*** and select PNG, **not** *"export"*. That's it!

*Made this answer based on a comment from [Yorik](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/39602/yorik)*

Comment: As of CC 2023, this is now "Save a Copy..." rather than "Save As..."

Answer (score 0):

Use artboards, then right click on the artboard -> Quick Export as PNG. However, you will need Photoshop CS6 or newer.

Comment: The result is again a file with lower dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop seems limited to a specific size on export.

A workaround is to **save the image as PSD file and use an external tool to create a PNG**.

**Note**: It may be necessary to merge the Layers in the PSD file.

Comment: Why is "save as..." > file-type "PNG" not an option? Works for me.